# Knockout: custom binding update not firing on computed field

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding, dom-events

I'm trying to render a cart with a table using Knockout.

I've a Cart entity and a CartItem entity:

```
var CartItem = function(product, qty){
    var self = this;
    self.product = ko.observable(product);
    self.qty = ko.observable(qty);
    self.title = ko.computed(...);
    self.unitPrice = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.product().price();
    });
    self.price = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.unitPrice()*self.qty();
    });
}

var Cart = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.total = ko.computed(function(){
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(ko.utils.arrayMap(self.items(), function(i){ return i.price() }), function(price){
            total += price;
        });
        return total;
    });
}
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Total:</td>
      <td data-bind="price: cart.total"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: cart.items">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
      <td data-bind="price: unitPrice"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: qty"></td>
      <td data-bind="price: price"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, i've create a 'price' binding to render the price, this is the code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.price = {
    init :  ko.bindingHandlers.text.init,
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var text =  '€ ' + value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1 ");
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function(){ return text; }, allBindings, data, context);
    }
};
```

The custom binding 'price' works for the cart items but not for the cart.total, nothing is rendered.

I've inserted a console.log(element) in the price binding and just the cart items are printed when the cart is updated and i can't figure out why.

Using instead 'text: cart.total' it works.

Comment: Here, I've created a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/q1z8kqxr/. I had to add some missing code, but it seems to works ok, or not?

Comment: Thank you @IlyaLuzyanin with your jsfiddle i've discovered the mistake! I've included the binding after starting the application, you can see the buggy version here: http://jsfiddle.net/q1z8kqxr/1/

Answer (score 1):

The js with the custom binding was included after the start of the knockout application.

I've included the custom binding before it and now it works.